# Returning variable from nested function to global scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope, paradigms

I have a bunch of nested functions, some of which return values that I would like to get out to the global scope.  What is the best way to do this? This is my example:

```
function mainFunction(){
      function A(){
            //somecode
            return valueA;
      }
      function B(){
           //somecode
           return {valueB1: valueB1, valueB2: "N/A"};
      }
      return {Avalue: A(), Bvalue: B().valueB1}
}
```

Comment: Your solution is currently working but I suppose you want something cleaner ?

Comment: Yeah works. Which answer do you expect?

Comment: A lot of things 'work', but yes, I was thinking there might be something more efficient that I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a *block statement* and *var* for stuff you want to share and *let/const* for private things:

```
{
 //private
 const func1 = function(){
   return "works";
 };
 //public
 var result1 = func1();
}
```

So you can access

```
console.log(result1);
```

but not the function itself.